# I don't know what wrong with my code I'm try many to debug but it didn't run

Tags: processing

I don't know what wrong with this:

```java
float [] x,y,d;
float [] vx,vy;
float [] x1,y1,d1;
float [] vx1,vy1;
void setup(){
  size(800,800);
  x = new float[5];
  y = new float[5];
  d = new float[5];
  vx = new float[5];
  vy = new float[5];
  x1 = new float[5];
  y1 = new float[5];
  d1 = new float[5];
  vx1 = new float[5];
  vy1 = new float[5];
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    x[i] = random(width);
    y[i] = random(height);
    d[i] = random(4);
    x1[i] = random(width);
    y1[i] = random(height);
    d1[i] = random(4);
    vx[i] = random(-10,10);
    vy[i] = random(-10,10);
    vx1[i] = random(-10,10);
    vy1[i] = random(-10,10);
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(#0799E5);
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    vichea(x[i], y[i], 5);
    vichea1(x1[i], y1[i], d1);
    x[i] += vx[i];
    y[i] += vy[i];
    x1[i] += vx1[i];
    y1[i] += vy1[i];

    if(x[i]>width  x[i]<0) {vx[i] = -vx[i]; }
    if(y[i]>width  y[i]<0) {vy[i] = -vy[i]; }
    if(x1[i]>width  x1[i]<0) {vx1[i] = -vx1[i]; }
    if(y1[i]>width  y1[i]<0) {vy1[i] = -vy1[i]; }
  
  } else if(i == 3) {
    x[i] = mouseX;
    y[i] = mouseY;
  }

  if (i<5) vichea(x[i], y[i], d[i]);
  else vichea1 (x1[i], y1[i], d1);
}
}

void keyPressed() {
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if (key == 'a') x[i] -= 8;
    else if (key == 'd') x[i] += 8;
    else if (key == 'w') y[i] -= 8;
    else if (key == 's') y[i] += 8;
    else {
      x1[i] = mouseX;
      y1[i] = mouseY;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use an editor with syntax highlighting and auto-formatting, and it should tell you exactly what's wrong: your `else if` in your `draw` method should not have that `}` in front of it. The `if` statement above it already has that closing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

First : when you put multiple conditions in a `if()` statement, you have to precise how they must be interpreted : if it's a or b, put a `||` (or operator) between them. If the two conditions must be valid then put an `&&` (and operator). In your case, I guessed you needed some `||` but you didn't explain what the code was supposed to do so I'm not sure.

Second : You've put some `if()` and `else` statement with some conditions on the variable `i` **outside** the `for` loop in which `i` was declared. The problem there is that `i` doesn't exist there, it's *scope* is only the inside of the for loop.

Third : The functions `vichea()` and `vichea1()` aren't declared so the computer doesn't know what to do with them.

Fourth : When you post a question, try to be more specific. We can't read your mind to know what you need so you have to tell for instance what your code is supposed to do, the error messages you get, ... Because I've so little information, I cant help you more than that. But anyway, here is my version of your code in which the two first problems don't cause an error anymore :

```java
float [] x, y, d;
float [] vx, vy;
float [] x1, y1, d1;
float [] vx1, vy1;

void setup() {

  size(800, 800);

  x = new float[5];
  y = new float[5];
  d = new float[5];

  vx = new float[5];
  vy = new float[5];

  x1 = new float[5];
  y1 = new float[5];

  d1 = new float[5];

  vx1 = new float[5];
  vy1 = new float[5];

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {

    x[i] = random(width);
    y[i] = random(height);

    d[i] = random(4);

    x1[i] = random(width);
    y1[i] = random(height);

    d1[i] = random(4);

    vx[i] = random(-10, 10);
    vy[i] = random(-10, 10);

    vx1[i] = random(-10, 10);
    vy1[i] = random(-10, 10);
  }
}

void draw() {

  background(#0799E5);

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {


    vichea(x[i], y[i], 5);
    vichea1(x1[i], y1[i], d1);

    x[i] += vx[i];
    y[i] += vy[i];

    x1[i] += vx1[i];
    y1[i] += vy1[i];

    if (x[i]>width || x[i]<0) {
      vx[i] = -vx[i];
    }

    if (y[i]>width || y[i]<0) {
      vy[i] = -vy[i];
    }

    if (x1[i]>width || x1[i]<0) {
      vx1[i] = -vx1[i];
    }

    if (y1[i]>width || y1[i]<0) {
      vy1[i] = -vy1[i];
    }
    if (i == 3) {
      x[i] = mouseX;
      y[i] = mouseY;
    }
    if (i<5) vichea(x[i], y[i], d[i]);

    else vichea1 (x1[i], y1[i], d1);
  }
}


void keyPressed() {

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {

    if (key == 'a') x[i] -= 8;

    else if (key == 'd') x[i] += 8;

    else if (key == 'w') y[i] -= 8;

    else if (key == 's') y[i] += 8;

    else {

      x1[i] = mouseX;

      y1[i] = mouseY;
    }
  }
}
```

*PS : I'm impressed your question didn't get roasted more than that. Usually, unclear questions are quickly disliked and closed*